# what is the difference events and tasks?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I am learning event loop, but I don't distinguish terminology about events and tasks.In the event loop context,I can understand "task" in MDN,

> tasks are triggered by events.A task is any JavaScript code which is scheduled to be run by the standard mechanisms such as initially starting to run a program, an event callback being run, or an interval or timeout being fired.

Async Tasks are triggered by events.
Can I understand that events are tasks that executed in another thread?
what is event in the event loop?

Comment: The wording in this article is quite unfortunate indeed. `Event` is the name of an object used to signal external "occurances" as the specs call them. Here they used "event" to mean such an *occurance*, not the Objects we can add listeners for in JS. Also, they go quite fast in saying that "A task is [...] JavaScript code". It's not. Most queued task will indeed ultimately try to [call JS](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#call-a-user-objects-operation), but they don't necessarily have JS to call, and moreover, tasks don't do only that, remember that browsers aren't written in JS.

Comment: I now see that I got duped by the typo in the specs's anchor to https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#action-versus-occurance So the correct spelling everywhere in my comments on this page is obviously "occurrence". (I opened a PR to fix the typo at the specs).

Comment: I thinking back to the design of systems in control engineering, system design need think the impact of real-world external disturbances. Understand why events are signals. For Web systems, timer events、network request events、click events, and so on may change state variables of the web system, so the system needs to respond（callback function）to do something. This state variable (signal) refer to the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are signals that tell the event loop that a task is now ready to run. They are not part of the event loop, they come from outside. Examples are DOM events (such as clicks, keyboard events etc), network events (readystatechange, progress), timer events (from `setTimeout`). Events are not tasks themselves. They may or may not be fired by another thread - often enough, the event loop polls for them.

Comment: "often enough, the event loop polls for them" I am not sure this happens so often actually. I could see the timers queue being polled,, but I *think* other "occurances" are passed to the event-loop through [IPC](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication/) by helper processes, most of these themselves put there by the OS directly. I used to have a link to a Chrome blog post about something along the lines of "from a click to a pixel" that went the whole way, but I can't find it anymore...

Comment: @Kaiido I was thinking of nodejs actually, which according to my understanding uses `epoll` somewhere within libuv

Answer (score 0):

Events do not occur in the event loop. When an event is dispatched, the callback function that must be executed is pushed onto the macrotask queue. There is no designated place for events inside the event loop, since events are not functions themselves. (macrotask and task is the same thing)

To give you a concrete example, let's say you have a button and a user clicks that button. When the user clicks that button, the callback function that must be executed is pushed onto the macrotask queue and **when the call stack is completely empty** the event loop will push the callback function from the macrotask queue onto the call stack. There is also a microtask queue but I don't want to confuse you.

I suggest reading the following articles that perfectly describe the event loop  in chrome and how it works:

- https://towardsdev.com/event-loop-in-javascript-672c07618dc9
- https://blog.insiderattack.net/javascript-event-loop-vs-node-js-event-loop-aea2b1b85f5c
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28AXSTCpsyU&ab_channel=TraversyMedia ( I don't quite agree with everything he says, but it's a good starting point. I suggest reading the articles first. )

Comment: That serhiikoziy.medium.com article is pretty bad. The distinction between "personal" and "customer" tasks is weird, and their description of microtasks is outright wrong.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, i've deleted it. I forgot to remove it from my bookmarks, thx

Comment: "*When an event is dispatched*" - actually, that term is used for synchronously running the handlers. The terminology used by the spec is to "queue a task to create and [dispatch an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch)" (or short: "queue a task to [fire an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire)"), so the dispatching happens *inside* the task. I'm pretty sure @Kaiido know what the proper term for the original event occurrence is

Comment: @Bergi, yep you're right. The term used by the specs is apparently ["occurance"](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#action-versus-occurance). And indeed this answer is pretty misleading. An *occurance*, then, will be signaled to the event loop by queuing a task, task which will indeed initiate and dispatch an Event object and as part of this dispatch call the JS handlers if any. The callback itself is not a task, and some events aren't dispatched from a task, like synthetic events obviously, but also the ones triggered in the update-the-rendering phase, like scroll events or WebAnimation ones etc.